# How to export large XLS with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I need to build and export rather complicated XLS table. To do so I was following RailsCast [Exporting CSV and Excel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) tutorial. For small sample of the table it worked perfectly, but when I tried to export full table of about 21 000 cells it took too long. Heroku threw:

> Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

But in logs is see that took more than 4 minutes, but it completed eventually.:

> 2015-04-23T12:05:18.069312+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12
>   desc="Request timeout"
>   2015-04-23T12:09:14.876148+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered market_prices/index.xls.erb (266788.6ms)
>   2015-04-23T12:09:14.876474+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in
>   266805ms (Views: 62681.2ms | ActiveRecord: 204120.4ms)

Is there a way to speed up the process or to put the task somehow in "background" so it downloads the file, when it finishes creating it?

Answer (score 3):

The error seems to appear because the task is just taking too long.

You should include a background worker like [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), [delayed job](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) or [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).

Rails 4.2 added [Active Job](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/getting-started-with-active-job) which makes including background workers much easier.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of items here:

Without any code it difficult to determine where the problem lies. It sounds like a possible N+1 query (where you're not using preloading also eager loading associations. Eager loading associations load multiple records at once instead of requesting one record at a time. Normally when you make a request if you see a wall of text in your development log you have an n+1 query. The bullet Gem helps with this.

Here is a quick tutorial on this:

http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

If you do have everything preloading/eager loaded look at this:

I would look at the AXLSX Gem with crispychicken's response, it allows you to build the XLS/XLSX table as method on a class, or even make it it's own object, instead of erb. I have done this for cases where I need excel. To download it once it's complete the User would have to do this manually or you can email it to the user. I recommend emailing it to the user so it stays out of your public folder, which the whole world can see.

If you do not wan't to email you can use [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html) and it will not be in your public folder. It will ask the user to download it. typicall I make a reports folder in my tmp dir to store these files until they are sent to be downloaded.